# How to install conda packages with "conda list" output txt

Tags: python, anaconda

I am **given** a `package_conda.txt` file with form as follows.

```
# packages in environment at /scratch/xxxx/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
absl-py                   0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
...
...
```

This file is generated by command `conda list > package_conda.txt`

I tried installing the listed packages by `conda install --file package_conda.txt` but was given the error message as :

```
CondaValueError: could not parse '_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0' in: package_conda.txt
```

Comment: You will want to use the `--export` flag of conda list, see: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/list.html

Comment: @cel I am **given** such a txt file and would like to install all the packages with the corresponding version without elaborating on the parsing of this txt file.

Comment: If you do not have the option to get the file exported with the `-e` flag, I think you will have to reformat the file by hand (it is simply in the wrong format). I am not sure though, maybe there is a way around.

Comment: This is answered in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65912328/11213215) by converting the file to a yaml file which conda can read.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use with conda you need to:

```
conda list -e > package_conda.txt
conda create --name <env> --file package_conda.txt
```

But this cannot be used with pip, For pip:

```
pip freeze > package_conda.txt
pip install -r package_conda.txt
```

Comment: `And using pip is much prefered.` - this is a bold statement and may need support.

Comment: Just wanted to state it is easier to use and it can be used in both the installation types (pip and conda) as well. And conda's format doesn't have a `==` rather it has a `=` with packages which may cause errors while used with pip or any other.

Comment: conda and pip are different package managers with different purposes, they are not interchangeable `pip freeze` e.g. will not be able to export non-python dependencies.

Comment: Yes, there are several downsides of using pip apart from conda in several cases, my bad. Edited my answer, Thanks @cel.

Comment: Note that the YAML format used by `conda env` does include Pip-installed packages. `conda env export > environment.yaml` and `conda env create -f environment.yaml`