# Conda: how to add packages to environment from log (not yaml)?

Tags: environment, miniconda

I'm doing an internship (= yes I'm a newbie). My supervisor told me to create a conda environment. She passed me a log file containing many packages.

A quick qwant.com search shows me [how to](https://towardsdatascience.com/manage-data-science-and-machine-learning-environments-using-conda-42b9b2f0689a) create envs via the

```
conda env create --file env_file.yaml
```

The file I was give is however NOT a yaml file it is structured like so:

```
# packages in environment at /home/supervisors_name/.conda/envs/pancancer:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
bedtools                  2.29.2               hc088bd4_0    bioconda
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0
```

The file contains 41 packages = 44 lines including comments above.  For simplicity I'm showing only the first 7.

1. Appart from adding `env name` (see 2. below), is there a way to use the file **as it is** to generate an environment with the packages?

I ran the cmd using

```
conda env create --file supervisors.log.txt

SpecNotFound: Environment with requirements.txt file needs a name
```

2. Where in the file should I put the name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install everything from a \`conda list\` output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65911763/install-everything-from-a-conda-list-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright, so, it seems that they give you the output of `conda list` rather than the .yml file produced by conda with `conda env export > myenv.yml`. Therefore you have two solutions:

1. You ask for the proper file and then proceed to install the env with conda built-in pipeline
2. If you do not have any access on the proper file, you could do one of the following:

   i) Parse with python into a proper .yml file and then do the conda procedure.

   ii) Do a bash script, downloading the packages listed in the file she gave you.

This is how I would proceed, personally :)

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no other SO post on this error, for people of the future: I got this error just because I named my file conda_environment.txt instead of conda_environment.yml. Looks like the yml extension is mandatory.