# conda create an environment without yaml or text file

Tags: python-3.x, pip, conda

I deleted a conda environment by mistake, and I do not have a yaml/text file containing the list of libraries. However, I have the following data:

| Name | Version | Build | Channel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| _tflow_select | 2.1.0 | gpu | anaconda |
| absl-py | 0.13.0 | pypi_0 | pypi |
| aiohttp | 3.6.3 | py37he774522_0 | anaconda |
| alabaster | 0.7.12 | pypi_0 | pypi |
| anyio | 2.0.2 | pypi_0 | pypi |
| appdirs | 1.4.4 | pypi_0 | pypi |
| argon2-cffi | 20.1.0 | py37he774522_1 | anaconda |
| ase | 3.21.0 | pypi_0 | pypi |
| asgiref | 3.3.1 | pypi_0 | pypi |
| astor | 0.8.1 | py37_0 | anaconda |
| astroid | 2.5.2 | pypi_0 | pypi |
| async-timeout | 3.0.1 | py37_0 | anaconda |
| async_generator | 1.10 | py37h28b3542_0 | anaconda |
| attrs | 20.2.0 | py_0 | anaconda |
| azure-core | 1.10.0 | pypi_0 | pypi |
| azure-eventhub | 5.1.0 | pypi_0 | pypi |
| azure-storage-blob | 12.6.0 | pypi_0 | pypi |

Please note that above table is a just the first few libraries present in the environment.
Can anyone please suggest me a way to create an environment using the following information?
Please do not ask me to install the libraries one by one as there are many libraries to be installed. Also, do not suggest me to create a .yml/.txt file and then use conda/pip to install all of them at a go, as putting everything in the correct format would take a lot of time.
Please let me know if those two are the only solutions to this problem.

Comment: This looks like the output from `conda list`. Is that what you have? I made a script for converting to YAML - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65912328/570918.

Comment: Thank you so much @merv, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merv's comment to my question:

> This looks like the output from the `conda list`. Is that what you have?
> I made a script for converting to YAML - see
> stackoverflow.com/a/65912328/570918

I referred to that link, and it helped me resolve my problem.
Thanks, Merv.
There's another workaround for this problem which is quite tedious, so I recommend people facing similar issues to follow Merv's answer.