# CondaValueError: could not parse 'abseil-cpp 20211102.0 h6b3803e_1 conda-forge' in: requirements.txt

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, conda, requirements.txt, conda-forge

I'm trying to run a github repository for the first time, but it has a lot of interdependent files (.py, .ipynb, requirements.txt and .json).
[***Repo link***](https://github.com/UditGupta10/GPT-InvestAR)

So firstly I've tried to clone the repository on a jupyter notebook after having created an environment on Anaconda.Navigator and then have done:
`!git clone https://github.com/UditGupta10/GPT-InvestAR`

After this, firstly I've sought to download all requirements by doing the following (in the modeling_and_return_estimation.ipynb notebook which I've got in the enviroment after cloning) by doing the following:

`!conda install --file requirements.txt --yes`

It gave me this error:

```
CondaValueError: could not parse 'abseil-cpp                20211102.0           h6b3803e_1    conda-forge' in: requirements.txt
```

```
# packages in environment at /Users/uditg/anaconda3/envs/llm:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
abseil-cpp                20211102.0           h6b3803e_1    conda-forge
accelerate                0.21.0                   pypi_0    pypi
aiohttp                   3.8.4           py311heffc1b2_1    conda-forge
aiosignal                 1.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
annotated-types           0.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
appnope                   0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py311he2be06e_3    conda-forge
arrow-cpp                 11.0.0               hc7aafb3_1  
asttokens                 2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-lru                 2.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             4.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
attrs                     23.1.0             pyh71513ae_1    conda-forge
aws-c-common              0.6.8                h80987f9_1  
aws-c-event-stream        0.1.6                h313beb8_6  
aws-checksums             0.1.11               h80987f9_2  
aws-sdk-cpp               1.8.185              ha71a6ea_1  
babel                     2.12.1             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backoff                   1.11.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.12.2             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
bleach                    6.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.82.0               h6e6338a_1    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.9                h1a8c8d9_9    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h1a8c8d9_9    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.0.9           py311ha397e9f_9    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h3422bc3_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.19.1               hb547adb_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.7.22            hf0a4a13_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.7.22          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1          py311hae827db_3    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
chroma-hnswlib            0.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
chromadb                  0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.5           unix_pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
clickhouse-connect        0.6.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
coloredlogs               15.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
comm                      0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
contourpy                 1.1.0           py311he4fd1f5_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dataclasses               0.8                pyhc8e2a94_3    conda-forge
dataclasses-json          0.5.9                    pypi_0    pypi
datasets                  2.13.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.7           py311ha397e9f_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dill                      0.3.6              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
docx2txt                  0.8                      pypi_0    pypi
einops                    0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
exceptiongroup            1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fastapi                   0.99.1                   pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.12.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
flit-core                 3.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.42.1          py311heffc1b2_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               hd633e50_1    conda-forge
frozenlist                1.4.0           py311heffc1b2_0    conda-forge
fsspec                    2023.6.0           pyh1a96a4e_0    conda-forge
gflags                    2.2.2             hc88da5d_1004    conda-forge
glog                      0.5.0                h5c6a83d_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.2.1                h9f76cd9_0    conda-forge
gmpy2                     2.1.2           py311h2ba9262_1    conda-forge
grpc-cpp                  1.48.2               hc60591f_1  
h11                       0.14.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
hnswlib                   0.7.0           py311hddbb800_1    conda-forge
html2text                 2020.1.16                pypi_0    pypi
httptools                 0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
huggingface_hub           0.16.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
humanfriendly             10.0            py311h267d04e_4    conda-forge
icu                       72.1                 he12128b_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        6.8.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        6.8.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       6.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.24.0             pyh5fb750a_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.14.0             pyhd1c38e8_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
joblib                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.14             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.18.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonschema-specifications 2023.6.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter-lsp               2.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.3.1           py311h267d04e_0    conda-forge
jupyter_events            0.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            2.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server_terminals  0.4.4              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jupyterlab                4.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.23.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.5           py311he4fd1f5_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.21.1               h92f50d5_0    conda-forge
langchain                 0.0.233                  pypi_0    pypi
langsmith                 0.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
lcms2                     2.15                 hd835a16_1    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h9a09cb3_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           17_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h1a8c8d9_9    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h1a8c8d9_9    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h1a8c8d9_9    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           17_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libcrc32c                 1.1.2                hbdafb3b_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   8.1.2                hc52a3a8_1    conda-forge
libcxx                    16.0.6               h4653b0c_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.18                 h1a8c8d9_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         hc8eb9b7_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h642e427_1    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.12               h2757513_1    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.5.0                hb7217d7_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h3422bc3_5    conda-forge
libgfortran               5.0.0           12_2_0_hd922786_31    conda-forge
libgfortran5              12.2.0              h0eea778_31    conda-forge
libjpeg-turbo             2.1.5.1              h1a8c8d9_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           17_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.52.0               hae82a92_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.23          openmp_hc731615_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h76d750c_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.20.3               hb5ab8b9_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h27ca646_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.42.0               hb31c410_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.11.0               h7a5bd25_0    conda-forge
libthrift                 0.15.0               h73c2103_2  
libtiff                   4.5.1                h23a1a89_1    conda-forge
libutf8proc               2.8.0                h1a8c8d9_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.1                hb547adb_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.15                 hf346824_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h53f4e23_5    conda-forge
llama-index               0.7.8                    pypi_0    pypi
llvm-openmp               16.0.6               h1c12783_0    conda-forge
lz4                       4.3.2           py311h854b99e_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hb7217d7_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.3           py311heffc1b2_0    conda-forge
marshmallow               3.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
marshmallow-enum          1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.7.2           py311ha1ab1f8_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.7.2           py311h3bc9839_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mistune                   3.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
monotonic                 1.5                        py_0    conda-forge
mpc                       1.3.1                h91ba8db_0    conda-forge
mpfr                      4.2.0                he09a6ba_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
multidict                 6.0.4           py311he2be06e_0    conda-forge
multiprocess              0.70.14         py311he2be06e_3    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
mypy-extensions           1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-core            7.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.9.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  h7ea286d_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.1                      pypi_0    pypi
nltk                      3.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook-shim             0.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numexpr                   2.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.25.1          py311hb8f3215_0    conda-forge
onnxruntime               1.15.1          py311h17ae30d_2_cpu    conda-forge
openai                    0.27.8                   pypi_0    pypi
openapi-schema-pydantic   1.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
openjpeg                  2.5.0                hbc2ba62_2    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.2                h53f4e23_0    conda-forge
orc                       1.7.4                hdca1487_1  
overrides                 7.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.0.3           py311h9e438b8_1    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh1a96a4e_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    10.0.0          py311h095fde6_0    conda-forge
pip                       23.1.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
posthog                   3.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.17.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.39             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.39               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.20.3          py311ha397e9f_1    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.5           py311he2be06e_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h27ca646_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pulsar-client             3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyarrow                   11.0.0          py311h7575258_0  
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydantic                  1.10.11                  pypi_0    pypi
pydantic-core             2.6.1           py311h0563b04_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.15.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyobjc-core               9.2             py311hb702dc4_0    conda-forge
pyobjc-framework-cocoa    9.2             py311hb702dc4_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pypdf                     3.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pypika                    0.48.9                   pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.11.4          h47c9636_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-dotenv             1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
python-duckdb             0.8.1           py311h9ded451_0    conda-forge
python-fastjsonschema     2.17.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-flatbuffers        23.5.26            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-json-logger        2.0.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-xxhash             3.2.0           py311he2be06e_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.11                    3_cp311    conda-forge
pytz                      2023.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0             py311he2be06e_5    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.0          py311hb1af645_0    conda-forge
re2                       2022.04.01           h6b3803e_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h92ec313_1    conda-forge
referencing               0.29.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
regex                     2023.6.3        py311heffc1b2_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
responses                 0.18.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
rpds-py                   0.8.10          py311h0563b04_0    conda-forge
sacremoses                0.0.53             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
safetensors               0.3.1           py311h0563b04_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.8.2              pyhd1c38e8_0    conda-forge
sentence-transformers     2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sentencepiece             0.1.99                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                68.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.10               h17c5cce_0    conda-forge
sniffio                   1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlalchemy                2.0.18                   pypi_0    pypi
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
starlette                 0.27.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.12            pypyh9d50eac_103    conda-forge
tenacity                  8.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.17.1             pyhd1c38e8_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tiktoken                  0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tinycss2                  1.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               he1e0b03_0    conda-forge
tokenizers                0.13.3          py311h572acbd_0    conda-forge
tomli                     2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
torch                     2.1.0.dev20230715          pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                2.1.0.dev20230715          pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.16.0.dev20230715          pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.3.2           py311heffc1b2_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.65.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
transformers              4.30.2             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.7.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-inspect            0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing_extensions         4.7.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
typing_utils              0.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h71feb2d_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.16                  pypi_0    pypi
utf8proc                  2.6.1                h1a28f6b_0  
uvicorn                   0.23.2          py311h267d04e_0    conda-forge
uvloop                    0.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
watchfiles                0.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
websocket-client          1.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
websockets                11.0.3                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.40.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hb547adb_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h27ca646_0    conda-forge
xxhash                    0.8.1                h1a8c8d9_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h57fd34a_0    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h3422bc3_2    conda-forge
yarl                      1.9.2           py311heffc1b2_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                hbdafb3b_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.16.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               h53f4e23_5    conda-forge
zstandard                 0.19.0          py311hae4035a_2    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                h4f39d0f_7    conda-forge
```

**How do i fix this issue?**

Comment: Where did that file come from? That's not the right format for a `requirements.txt` file. Conda has its own format, but I think it uses YAML and I don' think this is that format, either.

Comment: Though it does look related to Anaconda... it lists `conda-forge` quite a bit

Comment: @Chris, I got the file from a github repository, (link above if necessary).

Comment: Well, whoever created it didn't do it properly.

Comment: I don't use conda myself, but I think that's the output from running `conda list`. And [it looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61895008/354577) there's no nice way to install packages from it. It would need to be recreated with `conda list --export`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65912328/570918 and my [scripts for converting plain `conda list` output to proper YAML](https://gist.github.com/mfansler/5a1a703d1ac6bb2139547003248c3827). I.e., you can get to a YAML with `awk -f list_to_yaml.awk requirements.txt`. You may want to use the option `-v no_builds=1` if you are not working on the same platform as the original authors. But definitely drop an Issue on the repository telling them they should provide outputs from `conda env export`, `conda env export --from-history` and/or `conda list --export` if they want others to use their repo.